# CKEDITOR: "CKEDITOR.plugins.add('...,{ init:function(editor).." in this what is "editor".?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I don't know this is an valid question. I have seen most of the CKEditor examples of plugin and dialog definitions are using the variable **"editor"**. I want to know what it is and from where its values are coming.

For example

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'sample',
 {
  init : function( editor )
   {
    alert( 'Editor "' + editor.name + '" is being initialized!' );
   }
 });
```

In this example line `init : function( editor )` having an "editor". I want to know what it is and its having all the functionality like above example `editor.name`. How these variable has assigned all these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `editor` is the instance of the JavaScript CKEditor object you are working on.

When CKEditor calls the `init` function, it passes its own instance as function argument (called `editor` in your example).

Here is the [API documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html) that lists all available members of an editor instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i get that instance or assign that to some other variables from outside of init function.

Comment: See `CKEDITOR.currentInstance` or `CKEDITOR.instances` in the [API documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html)